# ¿Cuál es la causa del error que obtengo al graficar un DataFrame con el índice de filas del tipo datetime64[ns]?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

Importamos en un DataFrame (df), cotizaciones cargadas en un fichero xlsx.  El índice del df lo constituyen las fechas y , a pesar de que hemos indicado **parse_dates = True**, es del tipo **object**. No obstante, con este df el gráfico de evolución de las cotizaciones es correcto.

A continuación modificamos el tipo de datos del índice, haciendo que pase a ser **datetime64[ns]**. Co este df el gráfico no es correcto.

¿Cuál puede ser la razón de este fallo?.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
#os.chdir("/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Ficheros_xlsx") 
df = pd.read_excel("Acatis.xlsx", sheet_name= "Sheet1", parse_dates=["Date"], 
                   index_col="Date",  na_values='n/a' )

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2851 entries, 15/12/2008 to  
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Close   2849 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 44.5+ KB

# Gráfico de linea
df.plot(figsize=(8, 6), color='green', title = 'Line Plot', fontsize=12)
```

[image: gráfica de evolución cotizaciones]

```
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], errors='coerce')
# Volvemos a hacer índice la columna Date
df1.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
# Gráfico de linea
df1.plot(figsize=(8, 6), color='green', title = 'Line Plot', fontsize=12)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la carpeta **Consulta 01-2021**, del enlace  [consulta 01-2021](https://github.com/akitxu/Consultas-Programacion.git), depositamos el notebook y el fichero xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin, tras meses de desconcierto, he dado con el problema.
El problema está en los archivos exportados del banco R4. Los archivos son descargados en formato .csv. Utilizando LibreOfficce, los preparaba para su importación con Python. Hice pruebas también convirtiéndolos al formato xlsx , con el mismo resultado a la hora de graficar.
Recientemente, hice la prueba de importarlos a Excel, utilizando Google Excel y, mi sorpresa fue ver lo siguiente en la columna con fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Importé el fichero en la hoja Excel, y formateé la columna como fecha. Al descargar esta hoja y abrirla nuevamente con LibreOffice Calc,  observé que antepuso un apóstrofe a las fechas, el cual tuve que eliminar utilizando la opción **Datos < Texto a Columnas.** Un poco complicado pero me ha resuelto el problema. Desconozco si es un fallo del sistema de exportación del banco o si lo hace intencionadamente para proteger la información, aunque la descarga que he realizado es autorizada por el banco.